# Equation with mean of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, characteristic-functions, means

In a proof I found the following conversion

$$E\left[|X|\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(Y)\right] = E\left[|X|P(a \le Y \le b)\right]$$

I understand, why $E\left[\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(Y)\right] = P(a \le Y \le b)$, but I do not understand the above equation. Why is it true?

**Note:** In my case I have $X=Y_i$ and $Y=V_n^i+\Theta \frac{Y_i}{\sqrt{n}}$. The random variables $Y_i$, $V_n^i$ and $\Theta$ are independent.

Comment: Is the inner probability on the LHS conditioned on X, or was it supposed to be outside of the expectation, or neither?  $E[|X|P(a \leq Y \leq b|X)]$ or $E[|X|]P(a \leq Y \leq b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was just a typographical error in the textbook. Instead of $E[|X|\cdot \mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(Y)]$ it has to be $E[|X| \cdot E[\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(Y)]]$. Then it is obvious, that

$$E[|X| \cdot E[\mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(Y)]] = E[|X| \cdot P(a \le Y \le b)]$$